# SQL while loop with scalar variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, declare, scalar

I've run this type of code several times before, but in another environment in another organisation and not exactly the same versions on the SQL Server. The example code down below is simplified, but it works as an example of my problem.

In this example I'm trying to do a loop over several years (the "ar" variable) and create a new table for every year in another database than where the original table is saved. The original table include all the years. The "ar" variable in the original table is an int.

My code looks like below:

```
declare @Ar int = 2007
declare @ArVC varchar(4)=''
declare @CreateTable varchar(MAX)=''
declare @DB varchar(MAX)='MIRK3utv'

while @Ar <= 2015
begin

set @ArVC = cast(@Ar as varchar)

set @CreateTable = '
    select *
    into ' + @DB + 'dbo.Tab_' + @ArVC + '
    from DBorg.dbo.OrgTab
    where ar = ' + @ArVC

exec @CreateTable

set @Ar = @Ar + 1

end
```

This gives me an error that says:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 34
>   The name '
>   select *
>   into MIRK3utv.dbo.Tab_2007
>   from DBorg.dbo.OrgTab
>   where ar = 2007' is not a valid identifier.

What am I missing here? I've searched the net and this forum for an answer but I can't seem to find a solution that works for me in this case.

Comment: You should use `QUOTENAME(@DB)` and `QUOTENAME('Tab'+@ArVC)` to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: And  `@CreateTable` should be `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to support Unicode named objects

Comment: And `@DB` should be Unicode too, preferable `sysname` type as it does represent a system object (a DB name)

Comment: And fianlly, pass the `@ArVC` as parameter to `sp_executesql` toa void the problems of embeding the value in the exec SQL: `set @CreateTable = N'select * from ... where ar = @ArVC` and the `exec sp_executesql @createSQL, N'@ArVC varchar(4)', @ArVC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute dynamic SQL you have two options: Either use `EXEC(@SQL)` or use `EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @Sql`.
Note that the first option include parenthesis - without them, SQL Server assumes you are attempting to execute a stored procedure - that's why you've got an error.

The code you've posted in the question is also missing a dot separating the database name from the schema name, but it does appear on the error message so I'll assume it's just a typo in the question itself.

You can run this code like this:

```
declare @Ar int = 2007
declare @ArVC varchar(4)=''
declare @CreateTable varchar(MAX)=''
declare @DB varchar(MAX)='MIRK3utv'

while @Ar <= 2015
begin

set @ArVC = cast(@Ar as varchar)

set @CreateTable = '
    select *
    into ' + @DB + '.dbo.Tab_' + @ArVC + ' -- added the missing dot
    from DBorg.dbo.OrgTab
    where ar = ' + @ArVC

exec(@CreateTable) -- Note the parenthesis!

set @Ar = @Ar + 1
```

Comment: The only reply so far to actually explain why OP's code generates the error.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes, the dot was an error by me when I entered the question. My code is in a somewhat "looked" environment so I can't copy it. The parenthesis did the trick. They're in my other codes so I just must have lost my brain there and it's quite amazing that I never noticed it under my hours of error checkning. :) Many thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
declare @Ar int = 2007;
declare @CreateTable nvarchar(MAX) = N''
declare @DB nvarchar(MAX)=  N'MIRK3utv'

while @Ar <= 2015
begin

    set @CreateTable = N'
select *
into ' + @DB + '.dbo.Tab_@Ar
from DBorg.dbo.OrgTab
where ar = @Ar';

    set @CreateTable = replace(@CreateTable, @Ar);

    exec sp_executesql @CreateTable

    set @Ar = @Ar + 1
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

WITH Years AS
(
  SELECT 2007 Ar
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Ar + 1
  FROM Years
  WHERE Ar < 2015
)
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 
              N'SELECT * INTO MIRK3utv.dbo.Tab_' + 
              CAST(Ar AS VARCHAR) + 
              ' FROM DBorg.dbo.OrgTab WHERE Ar = ''' + 
              CAST(Ar AS VARCHAR) + '''; '
FROM Years;

SELECT @SQL;
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

I don't see why you need to use the loop here

**[See the results here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a782c485980f613e96254a1c97da38d)**